# Prompt not working in google apps script

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, prompt

I am creating a google script meant to ask me a question, get the date, and put it all in a new document. It gets information through prompt. When I click `run`, it says 'ReferenceError: "prompt" is not defined. (line 16, file "Code")'. My code is as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

 if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

 if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

 today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
 var prompted = prompt('How was recycling today?');

 DriveApp.createFile('Recycle log for ' + today, prompted, 'GOOGLE_DOCS');
 logger.log('On ' + today + ', recycling statistics were:' + prompted);
}
```

How could I fix this? If I cannot, how could I do about the same thing?

Comment: "prompt" does not exist in Google Apps Script, "logger" does not either, please read the reference documentation and/or use the autocomplete feature (CTRL + SPACE) when writing a script in GS.

Comment: I fixed the `logger` and replaced it with `Logger`, which **does** exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google app script is based on JavaScript which is used to automate google apps as well as creating add-on or build web applications but google app script runs on server rather than client's browser, so it does not support native JavaScript functions like `alert`, `prompt` etc.

However, google app script provides [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/) which you can use to create a user interface for your input.

Moreover, if your script is [Document bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), you can use method like [getUi](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui) which will return you [UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) through which you can show popups and dialog like alert and prompt, or even design your own [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title) or [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showsidebaruserinterface).

For Example:

```
DocumentApp.getUi().alert("Hello world.");
```

or

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

Follow the [examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#promptprompt-buttons) in the documentation.

Comment: Well, if a document is not open, like if I just click 'run', would this work?

Comment: If you have a document bound script and you are using 'getUi' method and running directly from the editor, will cause the popup/dialog to appear on your document page not on the editor. If you are writing a web app in google app script then you will be using HTML service that will return Html response to your client.

Comment: What do you mean by `document bound script`?

Comment: Wait, I read the link in your answer, and I'll try a document bound script to do it..

Comment: note that "alert" and such are NOT native javascript functions. they are part of the browser DOM (window) api.

Comment: Yes @ZigMandel you said the truth, thanks for pointing that out :)